# Cannot write parameters json file after installing bugzilla upto 5.0.1 on new windows machine

Tags: windows, bugzilla

I am moving a 4.0.2 bugzilla install onto a new pc running bugzilla 5.0.1 under windows 2012. I have bugzilla installed on the new machine, I copied over the bugs database, and localconfig, and run checksetup.pl which runs fine. Everything seems ok except when I change a parameter, and try to save it, I get a write error

*Software error:
write_file './data/params.json.3972' - rename: Permission denied at Bugzilla/Config.pm line 287.
For help, please send mail to this site's webmaster, giving this error message and the time and date of the error.
[Tue Nov 17 11:41:02 2015] editparams.cgi: write_file './data/params.json.3972' - rename: Permission denied at Bugzilla/Config.pm line 287.*

Something permission problem is stopping the bugzilla scripts saving the changes away. The webserver is IIS8, and IUSR has write/read permissions on the bugzilla folders. Any ideas ?

Comment: Please add the code that generates this error. If this problem does not involve code, consider moving this to Server Fault instead.

Comment: This is not a code problem, I think it is a configuration problem for bugzilla. There is a menu to allow some parameters to be altered in a file. Bugzilla makes the changes in a temp file (which are worked when I check the file) and when you save changes in the menu, it moves that file into the current parameter file, but fails as the script does not have write permission.

Answer (score 0):

As tonyb61 said, the problem is that it tries to replace params.json with a temporary params.json.XXXX file and fails. This is a known issue but I can't recall where this was reported to Bugzilla. However the workaround is quite easy:

1. Log onto the server where Bugzilla is installed.
2. In the Bugzilla folder, go into the data folder.
3. Replace the params.json file with the latest params.json.XXXX that has your changes.

I suggest reporting this at https://www.bugzilla.org/developers/reporting_bugs.html.